# s3cmd: how to use exclude-from with a file list of excluded directories

Tags: backup, rsync, synchronization

I cannot seem to get the `--exclude-from=` option to work with my exclude GLOB file when synchronizing with my s3 bucket. Here is a trivial example to demonstrate:

I create the following file tree under my `/home/user`:

```
syncTest
    includeTest
         includeFile.txt
    excludeTest
         excludeFile.txt
    exclude-list.txt
```

The contents of my `exclude-list.txt`:

```
syncTest/excludeTest
```

Then I use the following `s3cmd` command, called under `/home/user`:

```
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]~$ s3cmd sync --exclude-from=syncTest/exclude-list.txt syncTest s3://my.bucket/lucas/
```

but my `excludeTest` directory is not excluded:

```
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]~$ s3cmd ls s3://lucas.backup/lucas/syncTest/
                   DIR   s3://lucas.backup/lucas/syncTest/excludeTest/
                   DIR   s3://lucas.backup/lucas/syncTest/includeTest/
2014-04-06 12:18        21   s3://lucas.backup/lucas/syncTest/exclude-list.txt
```

I also tried using the following contents for my `exclude-list.txt` file:

```
 excludeTest
 /syncTest/excludeTest
```

But it does not work either.

Any suggestions? In this example, I just want to sync my `syncTest` folder, but not the `excludeTest` subfolder, using a file with the `--exclude-from=FILE` option.

I am trying to follow the same format as `rsync`'s `--exclude-from=FILE` option, assuming that it is the same, because there is not much help for `s3cmd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it is not the best answer, I found something that works by adding the following to my `exclude-list.txt` file:

```
*syncTest/excludeTest/*
```

I found the answer here:

http://sourceforge.net/p/s3tools/bugs/81/

It is not intuitive, and I think it is a bug. I do not think that rsync has this problem, and it is probably specific to `s3cmd`. Very annoying!

I am interested in hearing more about this problem.

Are there better options for backing up to S3 using rsync or a similar tool?
Is there a better solution than/when using the `--exclude-from=FILE` option?